# The number of maximal subsets with sum less than $m$

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, ds.algorithms, complexity-classes

I've met this problem.
I would like to know to which complexity class it belongs.

#### Input

- a set of positive integers $I$,
- an integer $m$,
- an integer $n$.

#### Question

Is the number of $S \subseteq I$ such that

- $\sum_{s \in S} s \leq m$, and
- $\forall e \in I \setminus S,\ e+\sum_{s \in S} s > m$

less than or equal to $n$?

Comment: This seems better suited to cs.stackexchange.

Comment: @Yuval: are you sure?  It seems to be a special kind of counting problem, confined to maximal-weight elements below a threshold.  I don't immediately see a reduction.

Comment: @AndrásSalamon Last time I was told not to comment on questions before they get migrated, so I didn't stop to think about this one.

Comment: I can't find any $YES$ certificate. Moreover, a possible $NO$ certificate, a list of subsets,
could be of exponential size. That's why, to me, it doesn't look like this problem is in $NP$ or in $co-NP$.

Comment: @Yuval, I think what was meant is that when you think a question is *clearly* off-topic then don't post an *answer* to it on cstheory and wait till it is migrated. I don't think that is in conflict with commenting about the appropriateness of a question, e.g. you can reply to Andras by saying that there is an easy answer.

Comment: Perhaps a simpler notation for the problem is: $\sum_{s \in S} s \leq m < \sum_{s \in S} s + \min\{e\in I \setminus S\}$

Comment: At first glance, the problem seems NP-hard: given an instance of subset sum with elements $a_1= 1 \ll a_2,a_3,...,a_k$ (all $a_2, a_3, ...$ even) and an even target value of $t \geq a_2$ (the subset sum remains NP-complete even forcing those conditions), use your problem with $m = t$ and $n=0$. The number of subsets of $I$ that satisfy the condition $\sum_{s \in S} s \leq m < \sum_{s \in S} s + 1$ is not zero if and only if the original subset sum problem has a solution.

Comment: The question is obviously in $PSPACE$. I guess you are asking whether it can be put some below $PSPACE$.

Comment: Another note: the counting version of subset sum is $\#P$-complete, so (*at first glance* :-) I think that using the reduction sketched above you can prove that your problem is $\#P$-complete, too (one can use binary search to find the exact value of the number of $S \cup \{1\} \subseteq I$ that satisfies the condition)

Comment: I don't think that the problem is in PSPACE because the number of subsets is exponential.

Comment: @s_xavier: it is trivially in PSPACE: you just need to scan the 2^|S| combinations: for (i = 0; i < 2^|S|; i++) check if the corresponding combination (using the 1 bits of i) satisfies the condition, if yes increment the total counter. The loop and the counter take $O(log(2^{|S|}))=O(|S|)$ space, and the sum requires $O(\log \max(s_i) + |S|)$ space.

Comment: Ok I understand your argument. I was thinkîng àbout writting the solution

Comment: It is in PSPACE. I would like a more precise classification.

Comment: @s_xavier: #P-complete isn't enough?

Comment: sharp P complete is nice ... Do you think it is the most accurate possible classification ?